# How to query through all varchar columns for a specific char

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to search for the char ' - ' in all columns (and lines) of my table. Currently I have this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `my_table` 
WHERE (
    SELECT C.COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C 
    WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
) LIKE('%-%');
```

But, of course, this doesn't work because of the multiple values returned by the subquery. Any ideas of how to achieve this?

Comment: how many columns do you have?

Comment: I have 114 columns D:

Answer (score 2):

You can get the query with a `SELECT` on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and execute the query with a [Prepared SQL Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) on MySQL:

```
SET @query = '';
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ',GROUP_CONCAT(C.COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ' LIKE ''%-%'' OR '), ' LIKE ''%-%''')  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' INTO @query;

PREPARE stmtSearch FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmtSearch;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmtSearch;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=94436ef6617f61e3cb89986089105843)